# Facebook Graph api , post comment not showing up

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The following code in nodejs is what I am using to post comment to a facebook post ( photo ) :

```
      var messageBody = "Test"

      var graphApiUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
        + facebookObjectId
        + '/comments?access_token='
        + appToken;

      log.debug(site + " Posting to : " + graphApiUrl);
      var req = request.post(graphApiUrl, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err)
          return reject('Upload failed:', err);

        body = JSON.parse(body);
        if (!body || body.error) {
          var msg = "";
          if (!body) {
            msg = site + " Failed to update to facebook , invalid resource returned";
            log.error(msg);
            return reject(msg);
          }

          msg = site + " Failed to update to facebook : " + body.error;
          log.error(msg, body.error);
          return reject(msg);
        }


        log.info(site + ' Upload successful! Server responded with:', body);

        var postUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/" + body.id;
        log.info(site + " Successfully posted to facebook : " + postUrl);

        lastUrl.lastUrl = postUrl;
        return resolve(lastUrl);

      });
      var form = req.form();
      form.append('message', messageBody);
```

Which works fine and it replies with :

```
{ id: '10153975808047812_10153975989317812' }
```

However, the comment does not show up in the original post. 
This behavior is similar to what I see here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=POST&path=10153975808047812%2Fcomments&version=v2.5&message=this%20is%20a%20test%20comment

[image]

From what I read here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/comments/ it seems to be working (  If successful:

Name    Description Type
id
The newly created comment ID
string ) .

So why is the comment not showing up ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: is the app live? (app settings)

Comment: it is not live yet.but I can already make wall post and post photos . Just not comments yet

Comment: happens even when app is live . is there some secret step ? can someone point me to some working example of posting comment ?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing. Did you ever work this out @ShroukH.Khan?